# c++ using not owned pointer in destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I just start learning c++11 for a short time and met a problem I don't understand. Here is the simplified example I met in a code base:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class Dumpper {
 public:
  Dumpper(std::function<void()> func) : mDumpFunc(std::move(func)) {}

  ~Dumpper() {
    mDumpFunc();
  }

 private:
  std::function<void()> mDumpFunc;
};

class Object {
 public:
  std::string getInfo() {
    return "Object's information";
  }
};

class Base {
 protected:
  void InitDumpper(std::function<void()> func) {
    mDumpper.reset(new Dumpper(func));
  }
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Dumpper> mDumpper;
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived(Object* object) : Base(), mObject(object) {
    InitDumpper(std::bind(&Derived::DumpFunc, this));
  }
 private:
  void DumpFunc() {
    std::cout << "Call DumpFunc, object = " << mObject->getInfo() << std::endl;
  }

  Object* mObject;  // Not owned.
};

class Test {
 public:
  Test() {
    mObject.reset(new Object);
    mDerived.reset(new Derived(mObject.get()));
  }
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Derived> mDerived;
  std::unique_ptr<Object> mObject;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Test test;
  return 0;
}
```

Based on my understanding, when `Test` is destructed, `mObject` is destructed first, then `mDerived` is destructed, then `Base` then `Dumper`. When `Dumpper` is destructed, `mDumpFunc` is called, in which member function of `mObject` is called. But why the member function can be called after `mObject` is destructed?

Comment: Are you asking why using an invalid pointer *seems to work*?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. One perfectly valid runtime consequence of undefined behavior is code that looks like it works. Another is nasal demons.

Comment: You will see the problem if you try to access  some data member of the destroed object. object->getInfo() from compiler point of view looks like getInfo(object) and if you do not access data member of the object, you suppose that everything is ok, but this is only UB.

Comment: You seem to know more C++ than the person who wrote that code base :-)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. One more question: Is calling `Derived::DumpFunc` in `Dumpper` after the destruction of `Derived` an undefined behavior as well?